# how to make parent element get box-shadow when an input is active

Tags: css, input, css-selectors

I want to make an **input** that if the input is **active** then the **parent element** will get a **box-shadow**

and this is my code :

```
.searchbar input:active .searchbar{
    box-shadow: 0 4px 24px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 8%);
}
```

I want to make `.searchbar` get box-shadow when `input` (child element) is **active**

Comment: include your HTML

Comment: This is currently impossible with CSS. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [focus-within](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within)

```
<div class="parent">
   The parent div
 <input class="input" />
</div>

.parent:focus-within {
   box-shadow: 0 4px 24px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 8%);
 }

.parent {
  place-content: center;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Working example: [codepen](https://codepen.io/musama125/pen/mdpNboa)